# TalkBack should not read the contentDescription only read Activity label

Tags: android, screen-readers

Inorder to Adding Accessibility to my application i can add Contentdescription to ImageView and ImageButton. But Talkback could not read the content description, it spoke only of activity label setting in the manifest File.When I was googling in the developer community most of the developers that are interested in application for blind people reported the same issue.

[From Google developer forum](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=130)

Which screen reader could be better for reading contentDescription?...I tested with the following readers but none of them give expected result.

```
query back

clock back.

explore by touch(talkback).
```

Any comment will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

I can found the solution from following Link .
[Answered by Mr.Alanav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681283/android-acessibility-api-contentdescription/12336979#12336979)

Ice Cream Sandwich and above have an "Explore by touch" feature that allows users to simply touch the screen to hear feedback and does not require a directional controller.on below ics we need directional controller like di-pad or eyes free keyboard.

Comment: Eyes free keyboard Found in the following Link- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.inputmethod.latin